# Calculus resultant and equilibrant question

Tags: calculus, euclidean-geometry

Two forces of 40 N and 50 N act at an angle 60 degrees of to each other. Determine
the resultant and equilibrant of these forces.

Let vector u = 40N
Let vector v = 50N

I made a right angle triangle from the end of vector u onto v and calculated |u|sin $\theta$ = 1732.1N

Clearly it isn't the resultant though, this would really help me before my test thanks for all the help.

Comment: First begin by drawing the triangle formed by graphically adding the vectors u and v. Then draw in the resultant, which points from the tail of u to the tip of v. This isn't a right triangle, but the angle opposite the side formed from the resultant is 120 degrees. You can use the law of cosine to find the third side of the triangle as you have two sides and the angle between them. The equilibrant is the vector that cancels out the resultant

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the other guy's answer gives a different resultant.

Comment: Both results are the same, mine has less reliance on coordinates though the provided answer make it easier to visualize. The magnitude of the resultant is independent of coordinate system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [resultant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant_force) is simply the sum of the forces. You seem to have calculated a dot product instead (incorrectly, because $|u|\sin(\theta)\leq |u|$, so it can't be 1732.1N).

Choose your coordinate system such that
$$\vec{u}=(40N,0)$$
$$\vec{v}=(50N\cos(60^{\circ}),50N\sin(60^{\circ}))$$
Add the vectors to get the resultant
$$\vec{u}+\vec{v}=(40N+50N\cos(60^{\circ}),50N\sin(60^{\circ}))$$